# Page with cards/frames in a listview (X.Forms 4.6+)

Tags: xamarin.forms, cardview, absolutelayout, content-pages

I had a question about X.Forms. Does anyone know how I can build such a page in X.Forms?

Flow of the page:
The user must be able to create a note and/or make changes. I want to display these notes one below the other (preferably in a scrollable list view).

[image]
[image]

Here is my code implementation that isn't really working fine.

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Xamarin.Forms.TestPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,1,0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  />
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,0.9" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>
            <ListView>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame>
                                <Editor></Editor>
                                <Button x:Name="CreateOrChangeButton" Text="Create/Change" Clicked=""></Button>
                                <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Text="Delete" Clicked=""></Button>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Tried GridView?

Comment: Create a ViewCell which looks like the template in your image. You should use stacklayout or grid to layout your views inside Frame.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT do you have any samples (code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
<ListView RowHeight="300" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="White">

    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>mono</x:String>
            <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
            <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame Margin="40" BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="220">

                        <StackLayout>
                            <Editor Text="test" HeightRequest="150"></Editor>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Button x:Name="CreateOrChangeButton" Text="Create/Change" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
                                <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Text="Delete" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Brown" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. This is what I needed. I think it is useful to replace stack layout with Grid, so that it works well in terms of performance.